# Como remover uma Label que foi criada dinamicamente no VBA?

Tags: vba, label

O código abaixo, enviado pelo Luiz Vieira, cria Labels dinamicamente e uma função de tratamento de click para cada Label.

Gostaria de saber como utilizar o evento Click para remover as Labels que foram criadas dinamicamente.

**Criando as Labels:**

```
Dim Labels() As New LabelHandler

Private Sub CriaLabels(ByVal QuantidadeDeLabels As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Label As Control

    ReDim Labels(0 To QuantidadeDeLabels - 1)

    For i = 0 To QuantidadeDeLabels - 1

        Set Label = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "NewLabel" & i)

        With Label
          .Caption = "NewLabel" & i
          .Top = 50 * i
          .Left = 50
        End With

        Set Labels(i).Ctrl = Label

    Next i

End Sub
```

**Função de tratamento de Click no módulo de classes:**

```
Public WithEvents Ctrl As MSForms.Label

Private Sub Ctrl_Click()

    MsgBox "Você clicou no label de nome " & Ctrl.Name

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edelson, use a instruçäo abaixo:

```
Me.Controls.Remove Labels(0).Name
```

Altere o índice para excluir a Label desejada, neste caso, o índice é zero.

Eu costumo eliminar do último índice até o primeiro, para evitar problemas.

Comment: Obrigado Leo! Adaptei o código ao meu projeto e funcionou perfeitamente. Vou postar abaixo para o caso de alguém precisar:

Comment: Option Explicit

Public WithEvents Ctrl As MSForms.Label

Private Sub Ctrl_Click() 'Deleta Labels criadas dinamicamente

    Dim i As Integer

    If Ctrl.Name = "NewLabel3" Then

        For i = 0 To 3
            Ctrl.Name = "NewLabel" & i
            Form1.Controls.Remove Ctrl.Name
        Next i
    
    End If

End Sub

Comment: De nada, bom trabalho!